# How to write each value of grid view to a text file?

Tags: c#, winforms, text-files

I want to write the grid values to each line of a text file.

The grid is as follows.

[image]

I want to write values of SensposX, SensPosY and SensPosZ with a white space tab in one line and like this it should follow for the remaining 12 rows.

May I know how to write this?

Comment: Maybe a `StreamWriter` in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: So the question is how to loop through the grid rows ? Or the question is how to write to a text file ? Both have answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737436/looping-each-row-in-datagridview and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files

Comment: How do you set the datasource? Use the same source to loop through values and write it to file.

Comment: what is the DataSource for this grid?

Comment: The data source is a XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

To export a `DataGridView` to file, as a simple option you can use  [`GetClipboardContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getclipboardcontent(v=vs.110).aspx) methos:

```
grid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
grid.SelectAll();
var text = grid.GetClipboardContent().GetText();
```

Then you can simply use [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx) method to save contents to file:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);
```

*Note*

- You can select only columns or rows which you want to export. I used `SelectAll()` to export the whole grid.
- You can have more control on exported text using this signature of [`GetText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk904t3k(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

**Option 2**

You can use linq to select cell values which you want and join them to create the text representation of `DataGridView`:

```
var lines = new List<string>();
var headers = grid.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                            .Where(c => c.Visible).Select(c => c.HeaderText);
lines.Add(string.Join("\t", headers));
var rows = grid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                        .Select(r => string.Join("\t", r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                        .Where(c => c.Visible).Select(c => c.FormattedValue)));
lines.AddRange(rows);
var text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```