# Datagridview get values from all rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, json.net

My code only gets the values of one row. But my user writes text into many rows and I have to get all their values to write them into a JSON. How can I get the values from all rows?

```
var llist = new List<MyClass>();
var obj = new MyClass()
{
    Nachricht = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Value"].Value.ToString(),
    Datum = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["File"].Value.ToString()
};
llist.Add(obj);
string export = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { types = llist }, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(@Settings.Default.folder + "\\" + "upload" + "\\" + "export.json", export);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping each row in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737436/looping-each-row-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 4):

In that case you should get the rows from `SelectedRows` property using `dataGridView1.SelectedRows`. Loop through all the rows and do your processing like

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
  //whatever you are currently doing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate:
[Looping each row in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737436/looping-each-row-in-datagridview)

```
//Setup list object
var llist = new List<MyClass>();
//Loop through datagridview rows
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   var obj = new MyClass()
         {
             Nachricht = dataGridView1.row.Cells["Value"].Value.ToString(),
             Datum = dataGridView1.row.Cells["File"].Value.ToString()
         };
         llist.Add(obj);
}
//Write out JSON file
string export = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { types = llist }, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(@Settings.Default.folder + "\\" + "upload" + "\\" + "export.json", export);
```

Comment: var llist = new List<Nachrichten_Felder>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                var obj = new Nachrichten_Felder()
                {
                    Nachricht = row.Cells["Nachricht"].Value.ToString(),
                    Datum = row.Cells["Datum"].Value.ToString()
                };
                llist.Add(obj);
            } Exits suddenly, in Log I can see "system.NullReference Exception"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop through the data grid collection to get each row. Something like this:

```
Foreach(DataGridViewRow dgvr in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var obj = new MyClass()
    {
        Nachricht = dgrv.Cells["Value"].Value.ToString(),
        Datum = dgrv.CurrentRow.Cells["File"].Value.ToString()
    }
    llist.Add(obj);
}
```