# Is there a method of transferring DataGridView data to the Windows Registry?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, datagridview, registrykey

I am creating an application which allows users to enter/edit instrument details using the DataGridView control. On pressing save (from the Menu strip), I am wanting any data in the DataGridView table to be transferred to the Windows Registry - is this possible?

I can only seem to find information on adding to the Registry via a button. I created a simple registry application which lets you add and delete from the Registry via buttons on the form using the following code:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Sanaa");
        key.SetValue("Leonardo_edi", "Sanaa");
        key.Close();
    }
```

I have a smaller prototype version of my bigger application until I can get this part working, which can be seen below:

[I'd like each entry in the table to be a folder name within the Registry, with the different parameters such as "Age", "School" to be entries in this folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fBmI.png)

Comment: You should be able to get the values from the DataGridView, however allowing users the enter data directly into the registry sounds like a disaster waiting to happen. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @JohnG It is one of the requirements for a university project.

Comment: Ok... Then as MavisBeacon suggest loop thru the rows in the DataGridView like: `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)` then `string cell1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();` ...

Comment: @JohnG I'll try that, thank you! Out of interest, why is writing directly to the registry not a good idea?

Comment: Incorrect values or incorrect overwritten values in the registry can render your machine unbootable. The registry is something that needs careful attention when editing because invalid entries can possibly cause the computer to not boot properly. This is just my opinion and if this is a requirement for your project then you don't really have an option. But to your question, just loop thru the rows in the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737436/looping-each-row-in-datagridview)

Basically you use the logic you have to update 1 registry value, but apply it to each row in the data grid by looping through the rows.