# Compare multiple values from Datagridview

Tags: c#

[image]

On button click event I want to loop through the rows based on Category. And if the Datagridview contains Category with Frame, Lens and Consultation at a time. Then I want to show an alert. How to achieve this? I have tried foreach but no result.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewInvoice.Rows)
            {
                string ItemType = row.Cells["SubCategory"].Value.ToString();
                if(ItemType == "Frame" && ItemType == "Lens" && ItemType == "Consultation")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You can't select all items at once");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping each row in datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737436/looping-each-row-in-datagridview)

Comment: `ItemType` can not have 3 values at the same time. change your **&&** operator to ||

Answer (score 1):

Loop all the records and keep flag  of items which in the given list. Finally show the message if all the flags true

```
bool frame,lens,type;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewInvoice.Rows)
{
    string ItemType = row.Cells["SubCategory"].Value.ToString();
    if(ItemType == "Frame"){frame =true;}
    else if ( ItemType == "Lens"){lens =true;}
    else if (ItemType == "Consultation"){type =true;}
}
if (frame && lens && type)
{
       MessageBox.Show("You can't select all items at once");
}
```