# how to update MS-ACCESS database from datagridview with dapper in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datatable, datagridview, dapper

Previously I did a sql insert by looping with the datatable to the database but now I want to update to the database with dapper, please guide me so that I am not wrong in the method taken, because later this process will relate to the amount of stock item quantity.

Thanks

```
Public Class Form2
    Inherits Form
 Dim itrservice As New ItemtransfersService()
    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
 Public Sub New(item As ItemTransfers)
        Me.New
 DataGridView1.DataSource = itrservice.GetItemTransfersDetail(item.Invno)
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Visible = False
 TextBox1.Text = item.Invno
        TextBox2.Text = item.Created
 Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdate.Click
        If DataGridView1.RowCount = 0 Then
            Throw New Exception("Enter Item data item first")
        End If
        Dim obj = New ItemTransfers With {
                  .Modified = DateTime.Now
                  }
        itrservice.UpdateItemTransfers(obj)
        'For i = 0 To _myTable.Rows.Count - 1
        '    Dim detail = New ItemTransfersDetail With {
        '    '     .No = Convert.ToInt32(_myTable.Rows(i)(0)),
        '    '            .CodeProduct = _myTable.Rows(i)(1).ToString(),
        '    '            .Barcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(2).ToString(),
        '    '            .Colorcode = _myTable.Rows(i)(3).ToString(),
        '    '            .Size = _myTable.Rows(i)(4).ToString(),
        '    '            .Qty = Convert.ToInt32(_myTable.Rows(i)(5).ToString())
        '    '            }
        '    'itrservice.UpdateItemTransfersdetail(detail)
        'Next i


    End Sub
End Class
   Public Sub UpdateItemTransfers(ByVal Obj As ItemTransfers)
        Dim sql = $"UPDATE `Stocksout` Set `Modified`='{Obj.Modified}' WHERE `Invno`='{Obj.Invno}';"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql)
        End Using
    End Sub
    Public Sub UpdateItemTransfersdetail(ByVal Obj As ItemTransfersDetail)
        Dim sql = $"UPDATE `Stocksoutdetail` Set `CodeProduct`='{Obj.CodeProduct}',`Barcode`='{Obj.Barcode}',`Colorcode`='{Obj.Colorcode}',`Size`='{Obj.Size}',`Qty`={Obj.Qty} WHERE `Invno`='{Obj.Invno}' and `No`={Obj.No};"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql)
        End Using
    End Sub
```

formview(form2)

[image: formview(form2)]

Comment: How about you update your question with a clear and concise explanation of what about the above solution is not working as expected.  You’ve been asked this many times in many different questions, not to mention those questions and provided advice already all contain the information you’re asking for.

Comment: @Hursey , thanks for your response but I've got the solution

Comment: @dr.null , Is the answer I made not in accordance with the method even though I can get the results of the answer I made if not please guide from you, is it necessary to loop DataGridView or is there a way to do it via dapper or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This link provides a solution to my problem [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737436/looping-through-each-row-in-a-datagridview)!

```
Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdate.Click
        If DataGridView1.RowCount = 0 Then
            Throw New Exception("Enter Item data item first")
        End If
        Dim obj = New ItemTransfers With {
                  .Modified = DateTime.Now,
                  .Invno = TextBox1.Text
                  }
        itrservice.UpdateItemTransfers(obj)
  For Each item As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
Dim detail = New ItemTransfersDetail With {
                        .CodeProduct = CStr(item.Cells(2).Value),
                        .Barcode = CStr(item.Cells(3).Value),
                        .Colorcode = CStr(item.Cells(4).Value),
                        .Size = CStr(item.Cells(5).Value),
                        .Qty = Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells(6).Value),
                        .Invno = TextBox1.Text,
                         .No = Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells(0).Value)
            }
 itrservice.UpdateItemTransfersdetail(detail)
 Next item
        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully")
  End Sub
```