How to update from textbox to database when filtering bindingsource from textbox via dapper vb.net
I'm Trying to update from textbox to database when filtering bindingsource from textbox via dapper vb.net.
so I use a textbox control to filter the datagridview TXTNAME and TXTDATE
but I have a problem filtering for the date if I type 01 then it appears but if I type the full date it doesn't appear.
Please Guide Me
Thanks
Public Class Form1
    Private _criteriasBindingList As New SortableBindingList(Of Person)()
    Private bindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing
    Dim PersonService As New PersonService()
    Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdate.Click
        Try
            Dim people As List(Of Person) = CType(bindingSource.DataSource, List(Of Person))
            For Each person As Person In people
                Dim Update = New Person With {
                                 .TIME = TXTTIME.Text,
                                 .OTHERS1 = TXTOTHERS1.Text,
                                 .OTHERS2 = TXTOTHERS2.Text,
                                 .NAMEPERSON = person.NAMEPERSON,
                                 .DATE = person.DATE
                                }
                PersonService.UpdatePerson(Update)

            Next
            ' Do not forget to refresh grid.
            DataGridView1.Refresh()
            MessageBox.Show("Person In successfully updated")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Myapp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _criteriasBindingList = New SortableBindingList(Of Person)(CType(PersonService.GetPERSON(), IList(Of Person)))
        BindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource 'Set the data source.
    End Sub
    Private Sub myFilter(str1 As String, str2 As String)
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList
        ElseIf (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.DATE.ToString.Contains(str2)).ToList()
        ElseIf (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.NAMEPERSON.ToLower().Contains(str1)).ToList()
        Else
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.NAMEPERSON.ToLower().Contains(str1) AndAlso c.DATE.ToString.Contains(str2)).ToList()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TXTNAME.KeyDown
        Dim str1 = TXTNAME.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        Dim str2 = TXTDATE.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        myFilter(str1, str2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TXTDATE.KeyDown
        Dim str1 = TXTNAME.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        Dim str2 = TXTDATE.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        myFilter(str1, str2)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Person
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property NAMEPERSON As String
    Public Property AGE As Integer
    Public Property [POSITION] As String
    Public Property [DATE] As DateTime
    Public Property DAYS As String
    Public Property TIME As String
    Public Property OTHERS1 As String
    Public Property OTHERS2 As String
    Public Property OTHERS3 As String

End Class
Public Class PersonService
    Public Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Person.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    Private ReadOnly _conn As OleDbConnection
    Private _connectionString As String = GetOledbConnectionString()
    Public Sub New()
        _conn = New OleDbConnection(_connectionString)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetPERSON() As IEnumerable(Of Person)
        Dim sql = "SELECT PERSON.ID AS [ID],MASTERID.NAMEPERSON AS [NAMEPERSON],PERSON.AGE AS [AGE],[PERSON.POSITION] AS [POSITION],PERSON.DATE AS [DATE],format(PERSON.DATE,'dddd') AS [DAYS],PERSON.TIME AS [TIME],PERSON.Others1 AS [OTHERS1],PERSON.Others2 AS [OTHERS2],PERSON.Others3 AS [OTHERS3] FROM PERSON INNER JOIN MASTERID ON PERSON.ID = MASTERID.ID"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of Person)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
    Public Sub UpdatePerson(ByVal Obj As Person)
        Dim sql = $"UPDATE PERSON INNER JOIN MASTERID ON (PERSON.ID = MASTERID.ID) Set PERSON.TIME = '{Obj.TIME}',PERSON.OTHERS1 = '{Obj.OTHERS1}',PERSON.OTHERS2 = '{Obj.OTHERS2}' WHERE MASTERID.NAMEPERSON = '{Obj.NAMEPERSON}' AND PERSON.DATE = #{Obj.DATE}# ;"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class


Public Class SortableBindingList(Of T As Class)
        Inherits BindingList(Of T)

        Private _isSorted As Boolean
        Private _sortDirection As ListSortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending
        Private _sortProperty As PropertyDescriptor

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SortableBindingList{T}"/> class.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SortableBindingList{T}"/> class.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="list">An <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IList`1" /> of items to be contained in the <see cref="T:System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1" />.</param>
        Public Sub New(ByVal list As IList(Of T))
            MyBase.New(list)
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets a value indicating whether the list supports sorting.
        ''' </summary>
        Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property SupportsSortingCore As Boolean
            Get
                Return True
            End Get
        End Property

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets a value indicating whether the list is sorted.
        ''' </summary>
        Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property IsSortedCore As Boolean
            Get
                Return _isSorted
            End Get
        End Property

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets the direction the list is sorted.
        ''' </summary>
        Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property SortDirectionCore As ListSortDirection
            Get
                Return _sortDirection
            End Get
        End Property

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets the property descriptor that is used for sorting the list if sorting is implemented in a derived class; otherwise, returns null
        ''' </summary>
        Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property SortPropertyCore As PropertyDescriptor
            Get
                Return _sortProperty
            End Get
        End Property

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Removes any sort applied with ApplySortCore if sorting is implemented
        ''' </summary>
        Protected Overrides Sub RemoveSortCore()
            _sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending
            _sortProperty = Nothing
            _isSorted = False 'thanks Luca
        End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sorts the items if overridden in a derived class
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="prop"></param>
    ''' <param name="direction"></param>
    Protected Overrides Sub ApplySortCore(ByVal prop As PropertyDescriptor, ByVal direction As ListSortDirection)
        _sortProperty = prop
        _sortDirection = direction

        Dim list As List(Of T) = TryCast(Items, List(Of T))
        If list Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        list.Sort(AddressOf Compare)

        _isSorted = True
        'fire an event that the list has been changed.
        OnListChanged(New ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1))
    End Sub
    Private Function Compare(ByVal lhs As T, ByVal rhs As T) As Integer
            Dim result = OnComparison(lhs, rhs)
            'invert if descending
            If _sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending Then
                result = -result
            End If
            Return result
        End Function

        Private Function OnComparison(ByVal lhs As T, ByVal rhs As T) As Integer
            Dim lhsValue As Object = If(lhs Is Nothing, Nothing, _sortProperty.GetValue(lhs))
            Dim rhsValue As Object = If(rhs Is Nothing, Nothing, _sortProperty.GetValue(rhs))
            If lhsValue Is Nothing Then
                Return If(rhsValue Is Nothing, 0, -1) 'nulls are equal
            End If
            If rhsValue Is Nothing Then
                Return 1 'first has value, second doesn't
            End If
            If TypeOf lhsValue Is IComparable Then
                Return DirectCast(lhsValue, IComparable).CompareTo(rhsValue)
            End If
            If lhsValue.Equals(rhsValue) Then
                Return 0 'both are the same
            End If
            'not comparable, compare ToString
            Return lhsValue.ToString().CompareTo(rhsValue.ToString())
        End Function
    End Class

Table PERSON

ID  Age Position          DATE      Time    Others1 Others2 Others3
1000    25  IT          01-May-24               
2000    35  IT          01-May-24               
3000    19  ADMIN       02-May-24               
4000    22  ADMIN       02-May-24               
5000    37  ENGINEERING 03-May-24               
6000    42  ENGINEERING 03-May-24               
1000    25  IT          03-May-24   

Table MASTERID
ID    NamePerson
1000    Rey
2000    Jack
3000    Michael
4000    Dave
5000    Roberto
6000    Morgen


ado net is much easier to handle

@nbk ,
thank you for your response . Please guide me

try first https://stackoverflow.com/a/76965975/5193536

@nbk ,
I have made an answer in this post if there are suggestions or recommendations that I should improve in the code

I made it look like the problem was solved. If you have any suggestions, please do so
  Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdate.Click
        Try
            Dim people As List(Of Person) = CType(bindingSource.DataSource, List(Of Person))
            For Each person As Person In people
                Dim Update = New Person With {
                                 .TIME = TXTTIME.Text,
                                 .OTHERS1 = TXTOTHERS1.Text,
                                 .OTHERS2 = TXTOTHERS2.Text,
                                 .NAMEPERSON = person.NAMEPERSON,
                                 .DATE = person.DATE
                                }
                PersonService.UpdatePerson(Update)

            Next
            ' Do not forget to refresh grid.
            DataGridView1.Refresh()
            MessageBox.Show("Person In successfully updated")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Myapp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub
  Private Sub myFilter(str1 As String, str2 As String)
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList
        ElseIf (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.DATE.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy").Contains(str2)).ToList()
        ElseIf (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.NAMEPERSON.ToLower().Contains(str1)).ToList()
        Else
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.NAMEPERSON.ToLower().Contains(str1) AndAlso c.DATE.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy").Contains(str2)).ToList()
        End If
    End Sub



